# Flurry for Android devices without Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, flurry, amazon-appstore

We have an Android application being distributed in both the Google Play Store and Amazon App Store. As such, some devices will not have Google Play Services (Kindle-fire, Blackberry, etc.). Given that the Flurry Android SDK (4.0.0) now depends on Google Play Services ([see here](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Android)), what will happen to these devices?

Will Flurry simply do nothing? Throw an exception?

Does anyone have any workarounds?

Comment: Do you have access to a device where Google Play Services are not available? If so, it might be worthwhile to side-load your app and see what happens in that situation. Ultimately, you should speak with a Flurry representative to find out what the expected behavior is in this scenario.

Comment: Just fire up an emulator to test what happens - no emulators have google play services. My guess is that Flurry will log an error, but that's about it, it'll work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A well implemented SDK with dependencies on Google Play Services would check the availability using **public static int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Context context)** you can always use this before loading Flurry in your application.

In the case of Flurry I believe that it is OK to keep it there.

With BlackBerry 10.2+ you can install an APK through the browser so you can check the behaviour of your application in the platform.